# StreamBuilder not re-rendering the widget inside?

Tags: flutter

I created this code, what i want to happen is when i press on the button i want the piechart to re-render with the new values (which should be old values but the food value increased by 1)
I am using a piechart from  pie_chart: 0.8.0 package.
Deposit is nothing but a pojo (String category and int deposit)
the bloc.dart contains a global instance of the bloc, a getter for the stream and initialization of a stream of type 
Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';
import 'bloc.dart';
import 'Deposit.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'bloc Chart',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Map<String, double> datamap = new Map();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    datamap.putIfAbsent("Food", () => 5);
    datamap.putIfAbsent("transportation", () => 3);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PieChart using blocs"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<Deposit>(
              stream: bloc.data, //A stream of Deposit data
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                addDeposit(Deposit("Food", 1), datamap);
                debugPrint("Value of food in map is: ${datamap["Food"]}");
                return PieChart(dataMap: datamap);
              }),
          SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: Size(20, 10),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              bloc.add(Deposit("Food", 1)); //returns the stream.add
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void addDeposit(Deposit dep, Map<String, double> map) {
    if (map.containsKey(dep.category)) {
      map.update(dep.category, (value) => value + dep.price);
    } else
      map.putIfAbsent(dep.category, () => dep.price);
  }
}
```

Comment: try this, First close stream  then add new data

Comment: Where exactly should i close my stream? And also why would i want it closed while using it?

Comment: bloc.sink.close();
bloc.sink.add(Deposit("Food", 1));

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri if you close your sink how you can add anything to that sink? `close()` method docs say:  *"Tells the stream sink that no further streams will be added."*

Comment: @pskink that is bloc.close(); this is bloc.sink.close(); both are  different

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri so what is `bloc.sink` here? `StreamSink` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that the stream doesn't trigger new events. You don't have to close the stream to rebuild. I can't see anywhere in your code where you are triggering new events for the stream. Check below code to see a simple way how you can update a `StatelessWidget` using a `StreamBuilder`.

```
class CustomWidgetWithStream extends StatelessWidget {
  final CustomBlock block = CustomBlock();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: block.stream,
            builder: (context, stream) {
              return Text("${stream.data.toString()}");
            }),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            block.incrementNumber();
          },
          child: Text("Increment"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomBlock {
  num counter = 10;
  final StreamController<num> _controller = StreamController();

  Stream<num> get stream => _controller.stream;

  CustomBlock() {
    _controller.onListen = () {
      _controller.add(counter); // triggered when the first subscriber is added
    };
  }

  void incrementNumber() {
    counter += 1;
    _controller.add(counter); // ADD NEW EVENT TO THE STREAM
  }

  dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

Although this is a working code snippet, I would strongly suggest to change your widget from `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`, for two reasons:
* if you go "by the book", if a widget changes the content by itself, then it's not a `StatelessWidget`, a stateless widget only displays data that is given to it. In your case, the widget is handling the tap and then decides what to do next and how to update itself.
* if you are using streams, in a stateful widget you can safely close the stream, as you can see in the above code, there's no safe way to close the stream. If you don't close the stream, there might be unwanted behaviour or even crashes.

Comment: Ok bare with me here i am new to flutter. This code is just a test as my real goal is to have a button "add deposit" that would allow user to input a category and a price in which would then cause the piechart to update. I took a course on udemy that mentioned that bloc pattern is recommended by flutter. The piechart will be the body of my scaffold in my homepage and i am trying to avoid having the homepage be  a stateful widget. I am confused why the piechart is not being re-rendered even though it should (Streambuilder's stream has data being added to it by the bloc.add in the button

Comment: I don't completely understand how should i make my button interact with the widget, the idea in my head was simple. Button add event to stream, streambuilder updates the pie chart and i avoid making my whole homepage stateful. After this works i would try and make it so that automatically when i "add data" to the stream the map that is used by the piechart would also get updated, right now i'm manually updating it with addDeposit(). Also note that i tried replacing the PieChart with just a text displaying dataMap[Food] and that was being updated everytime i press the button.

Comment: Can you post the code from the ```bloc`` and where you init it ? I can't find the code for that.

Comment: Can you change the ```_data.sink.add``` to ```_data.add``` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my bloc file

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:testing/Deposit.dart';

class Bloc{

  final _data = new BehaviorSubject<Deposit>();

  Stream<Deposit> get data => _data.stream;

  Function(Deposit) get add => _data.sink.add;

  void dispose(){
    _data.close();
  }

}

Bloc bloc = new Bloc();
```